# Bibliography and Tex4ht

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, miktex, tex4ht, html

I am converting TeX containing references to HTML using `TeX4ht` installed under `MikTeX`. The program produces HTML but the bibliography is missing, any ideas? The following test.tex produces a clean test.pdf with `pdfLateX`+`BibTeX` under TexWorks, but `htlatex test.tex` generates test.html without a bibliography:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{section}{Publications}
\nocite{thesis}
\end{section}

\bibliographystyle{test}    % .bst
\renewcommand\refname{}
\bibliography{test}{}   % .bib

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks blackburn for the solution. I'm using a text editor (in my case TeXworks) that calls the typesetting engines in order and forgot to do this from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `test.bst` and `test.bib` with reference `thesis` in it, then the following lines in the command prompt will generate the `HTML` file with references (assuming your `TeX` file is named `test.tex`):

```
htlatex test
bibtex test
htlatex test
```